# Reading and Setting Rails Response Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post

I want to read the header of a request coming in to a Rails Controller...

How can I read in the header of the request to see what the request expects/wants back (in terms of formats) and send back data in that format?

example:

```
#in the controller receiving the request
def receive_req
   request.head #read value from header
   #if req wants json, format to json else, format to html etc...
   res = response
   res.head = "set appropriate header values"
   res.body = "data to send back in the body"
end


#in the controller making the req
def send_request
  Net::HTTP.post("/receive_req", "data", header_values)
  render #{response.body}
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `request.headers` hash as described [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-headers).

Of course, you might also choose to define your routes in such a manner that each endpoint provides output in only one format. Whatever works for your application.